# There was an error in the forked prpcess org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

When I am trying to perform the mvn test command, I got this error. It compile works fine. My code is running well I used to run this via Test-NG suite on Eclipse **but getting error when trying to run this via maven on command prompt...** Your assistance will be appreciable and thanks in advance.[Please find the screenshot link of the error below:-]

[Error_Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0Q7g.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this error by adding the commons-io dependency in pom.xml:-`

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
```

`